# bottom attached button not matching div size

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, semantic-ui

I'm working on a project and I'd like a form with a submit button, the example for the style of button I'd like in the semantic UI docs is:

```
<div class="ui bottom attached button">
  <i class="search icon"></i>
  Search
</div>
```

This creates a button that spans the whole of the screen.

So to create a rails form button I have:

```
<%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "ui bottom attached button") do %>
    <i class="search icon"></i> Search
<% end %>
```

which produces the HTML:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="ui bottom attached button">
    <i class="search icon"></i> Search
</button>
```

Which creates the same style of button but not spanning the screen. Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **fluid** class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    
    
    
    <div class="ui bottom attached button">
  <i class="search icon"></i>
  Search
</div>

<button name="button" type="submit" class="fluid ui bottom attached button">
    <i class="search icon"></i> Search
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this class to the button element:

```
class="ui bottom attached button full-width"
```